# What causes the shape error in numpy.dot when a vector is multiplied with a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

```
a= [1, 2, 3, 2.5]
b= [[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0],
    [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5],
    [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]]

print(np.dot(b,a))
print(np.dot(a,b))
```

Why does the first line print but the second line cause a shape alignment error?

"ValueError: shapes (4,) and (3,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 0) != 3 (dim 0)"

What calculation is numpy trying to do that will cause that error?

Note - I understand matrix multiplication.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Edit - Fixed some variable names

Comment: a, b and weights, inputs correct the name. and it is simply matrix multiplication or just take numpy_array.T.

Comment: The basic matrix multiplication rule is 'across rows, down columns', right?  That means the last dim of A is paired with the 2nd to the last of B - if they are both 2d.  If 1 or other is 1d, there are special documented behaviors.  (3,4) works with (4,); (4,) does not work with (3,4) (where the 2nd to the last is 3).

Answer (score 1):

Your example is one case from the np.dot docs:

```
dot(a, b, out=None)

Dot product of two arrays. Specifically,

- If `a` is an N-D array and `b` is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over
  the last axis of `a` and `b`.
```

It does not list a case for `a` 1-D and `b` N-D.

```
In [106]: a= np.array([1, 2, 3, 2.5]) 
     ...: b= np.array([[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0], 
     ...:     [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5], 
     ...:     [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]])                                               
In [107]: a.shape, b.shape                                                               
Out[107]: ((4,), (3, 4))
In [108]: np.dot(b, a)                                                                   
Out[108]: array([ 2.8  , -1.79 ,  1.885])
```

in `einsum` notation, note the common `j` index (last axis of both)

```
In [109]: np.einsum('ij,j->i', b, a)                                                     
Out[109]: array([ 2.8  , -1.79 ,  1.885])
```

`a` can be 1d, but it is paired with the 2nd to the last dimension of `b`, so we have transpose it to match (4,) with (4,3):

```
In [113]: np.einsum('i,ij', a, b.T)                                                      
Out[113]: array([ 2.8  , -1.79 ,  1.885])
In [114]: np.dot(a,b.T)                                                                  
Out[114]: array([ 2.8  , -1.79 ,  1.885])
```

`@`, `matmul` describes the 1d array case in a differently, but the result is the same:

```
- If the first argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by
  prepending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication
  the prepended 1 is removed.
- If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by
  appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication
  the appended 1 is removed.

In [117]: b@a                                                                            
Out[117]: array([ 2.8  , -1.79 ,  1.885])
In [118]: a@b.T                                                                          
Out[118]: array([ 2.8  , -1.79 ,  1.885])
```

Answer (score 0):

a is a vector (maybe matrix (1,4), but u should reshape it maybe)

b is a matrix (3,4)

so u can do only (3,4)x(4,1) or (1,4)x(4,3)

try weights * inputs.T or respahe inputs

try inputs * weights.T

Comment: I know how to fix the error, I don't know why the error occurs

Comment: Cuz u cannot do (4,1)x(3,4), u should do (1,4)x(3,4), so u should transpose a

Comment: If numpy would do these transpositions automatically, there can be so many bugs in code, which will be diffucult for u. U should explicitly specify these things, it's better for ur code

Comment: The shape of a is (4,) not (4, 1) or (1, 4). In matrix multiplication neither (1, 4) * (3, 4) or (4, 1) * (3, 4) lead to a defined answer. What  would like to know is why the first line prints but the second line doesnt.